# How to disable toasts (popups)?

Tags: toast-notifications

An example of grey and white note that I mean is, like when you copy something, a small grey background and white lettered bubble appears for a few moments saying '*copied to clipboard*'. My phone has some sort of malfunction where it dispays that prompt for several minutes at a time. Very annoying.

How do I disable that?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: Considering that "*it dispays that prompt for several minutes at a time*", possible dupe: [Android 11: how to disable persistent notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242016/44325)

Answer (score 0):

For disabling those particular toasts (when clipboard is accessed), turn off **Alert when clipboard accessed** from

Settings app > Privacy > Alert when clipboard accessed