# Android 11: how to disable persistent notification?

Tags: android-11, toast-notifications

I'm not sure what's the best name, and probably these are not even "notification" since I tried to surface the whole menu and submenu without success.

The only thing I know is that when I set up this new phone yesterday (an OPPO Find X3 Pro), at some point I did encounter a setting that allowed me to delay these notifications from the "default" (2 seconds as far as I remember) to 30 seconds.

As a result, there are some operations showing the output of their action (e.g. the contact app when you delete a contact says "1 contact deleted") for the above time in a kind of overlay that is impossible to remove. I simply need to wait for it to disappear after the timeframe.

This persistent clutter drives me crazy and I don't know where else I can search for it.

Is it my memory serving me incorrectly about the above setting, or did I really change something in the settings?

Comment: If you are talking about Toasts, there is no setting (at least in stock Android) to change their behavior.

Comment: Oppo has it's own customised version of Android, but I can't find any "Toast" in the settings. What other name this could have ... and where this might be sitting in the menu?

Comment: Consider checking [Popups, dialogs, notifications, toasts: what's the difference?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/52789/44325) and clarifying it, since toasts are per-app and there are no system settings for it.

Comment: So it's a toast ... the problem is that there is no toasts in the colouros from oppo.... and I still have that 30 seconds there, though I'm sure I changed something as it was 2 secs.

Answer (score 2):

So, after an unsuccessful attempt to get Oppo's support (they suggested a system setting factory reset), I was able to figure out the setting location for changing the toast length time on Android 11 and ColorOS 11.2.

Everything boils down to the Accessibility menu, particularly this one: **Settings -> Accessibility -> Time to take action.**

I basically turned it to 30 seconds causing the problem above described.
This was done mostly because of the "improper" description following that setting (description available only in the setting itself) as per the screenshot.

> Choose how long to show messages that ask you to take action, but are visible only temporarily.

[image]

Comment: After reading this answer, since it mentions "time to take action", I think this is for [snackbars](https://material.io/components/snackbars) which look similar to toast but allow additional actions.

Comment: No, I don't think that is the case. The notification I was receiving where exactly plain text with no further actions allowed. They were similar though, a rounder box with some text inside appearing at the bottom of the screen. Although, yes, I appreciate the "take action" bit.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be thankful more Andrea for this question. I confirm time to take action setting was the main cause of this issue. For those with similar problem: these are actually some toasts that don't react to touch or swipe. They just shown on screen for a certain amount of time and block any access to UI behind them. In my case they even block the keyboard. Oppo name them Notice

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is to:

1. Long touch the notification you want to disable
2. Select the gear button (settings)
3. Un-grant the permission to show notifications

You won't see notifications anymore of that app.

Comment: Those are not clickable ... I guess the other comment about Toasts might be what they are.