# "pop-up message" obstructing for 120 seconds, was 2s

Tags: notifications, screen, alerts

I have a new Motorola phone (moto g pure XT2163DL, Android 12), and it's giving me trouble.

For multiple apps, the "mini-notification" or "quick status message" that they display is staying asserted for way too long, obstructing my touch keyboard and other important functionality.

My older Android phone does it right. The messages pop up and go away after about two seconds.

On my newer phone the messages are staying up a full 120 seconds! Surely somebody has run into this before. Please, where is this setting, so I can fix it?! (An Android developer might know what this special message type is called. Is it an alert, a dialog box, a pop-up? Please let me know, as my searches will be much more useful!)

Pictures below:

"Saved Successfully." stays displayed 120 seconds:

[image]

Switching applications and rotating the screen doesn't make the message go away:

[image]

Sometimes the message is long and so much more troublesome! You can't touch-type on the keyboard while the message is hiding it! : "Opera Touch pasted from your clipboard" :

[image]

Comment: That is a "toast message". There should be a menu on Accessibility Settings similar to [the one on Oppo ColorOS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242016/44325).

Comment: That was it. "Time to take action". Inside of Accessibility --> Timing Controls. I changed it from 2 minutes back to default, and now it takes only the two seconds that it used to take. Those  "Toast" messages are not using that setting properly, since no action was required or taken! Thank you!

Comment: You should also be able to get rid of those "Toast messages" by clicking or tapping on them, or some other reasonable method. That's a bug in the Android operating system.

Comment: If you could act on a toast, it's called *snackbar*// It's there in the [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242016/android-11-how-to-disable-persistent-notification#comment322550_242088) linked for you by @AndrewT